# Remove user from Site, List and Library

Tags: security-trimming

In my environment we have various sites that have not been governed properly and users were assigned with out group membership. Now that they are gone the users are still listed as part of the site because they were never removed from the various lists, libraries or sites that they belonged to....

I found a great article that helped me identify what groups users belong to (http://sympmarc.com/2011/11/03/managing-sharepoint-site-user-memberships-in-multiple-groups-using-spservices/) but was wondering how i can tackle this issue...would anyone have any suggestions on how to audit through the various sites, lists and libraries i have for various users and remove them from them? or should i just look into some third party solution to tackle that issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got any replies to this but I have found a work around that is more of a manual process but it still gets the job done. It involves looking at the "All People" listing in your site collection. Something you can get to from really any site in the collection buy adding the following on to your URL String.

Example:

http://intranet.company.com/

Add on to the end of that: /_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0

This will produce the master list of users that are in your site collection and when you find users who are no longer in the company or need access to your collection you can remove them from anything they are attached to using this, just select the box next to their name and on the actions menu choose "Remove Users from Site Collection"